# Error message after using Internalization

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I installed Internalization module and made my website Turkish as default.
Now I receive this error message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning issued from file and directory permission.
This issues maybe useful for you.
[link1](http://drupal.org/node/1076762)
[link2](http://drupal.org/node/1076762)

Comment: "sites/default/files" and "/vhosts/mydomain.com/tmp/", I gave 777 persissions to these 2 folders then I tried to save "admin/config/media/file-system" but i still receive error. http://i48.tinypic.com/o6yb0z.png

Comment: I created a new directory then changed its permissions."sites/default/temp" ,now its working fine